# How to access an array using foreach in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data like below :

```
tab1,c1|c2|c3
tab2,d1|d2|d3|d4|d5
tab3,e1|e2|e3|e4
```

I need to convert it to as below in spark:

```
select c1,c2,c3 from tab1;
select d1,d2,d3,d4,d5 from tab2;
select e1,e2,e3,e4 from tab3;
```

I am able to get like this:

```
d.foreach(f=>{println("select"+" "+f+" from"+";")})
select tab3,e1,e2,e3,e4 from;
select tab1,c1,c2,c3 from;
select tab2,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5 from;
```

Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing where spark fits in your question.  What does the variable 'd' represent?

Here is my guess at something that may be helpful.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

mySchema = StructType([
  StructField("table_name", StringType()),
  StructField("column_name", 
    ArrayType(StringType())
  )
])

df = spark.createDataFrame([
                            ("tab1",["c1","c2","c3"]),
                            ("tab2",["d1","d2","d3","d4","d5"]),
                            ("tab3",["e1","e2","e3","e4"])
  ],
  schema = mySchema
)

df.selectExpr('concat("select ", concat_ws(",", column_name), " from ", table_name, ";") as select_string').show(3, False)
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------------+
|select_string                   |
+--------------------------------+
|select c1,c2,c3 from tab1;      |
|select d1,d2,d3,d4,d5 from tab2;|
|select e1,e2,e3,e4 from tab3;   |
+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: This is one of the options. I am actually looking to create via RDD.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `map` operation on RDD.

Assuming you have a RDD of `String` like:

```
val rdd = spark.parallelize(Seq(("tab1,c1|c2|c3"), ("tab2,d1|d2|d3|d4|d5"), ("tab3,e1|e2|e3|e4")))
```

with this operation:

```
val select = rdd.map(str=> {
      val separated = str.split(",", -1)
      val table = separated(0)
      val cols = separated(1).split("\\|", -1).mkString(",")

      "select " + cols + " from " + table + ";"
    })
```

you will get the expected result:

```
select.foreach(println(_))
select d1,d2,d3,d4,d5 from tab2;
select e1,e2,e3,e4 from tab3;
select c1,c2,c3 from tab1;
```

Comment: Hey pheeleeppoo,

Thanks you so much for the code. I was stucked in doing this. I did it in another way. Any way thanks for your time.

Comment: It could be useful for someone else share what you did and/or accept one answear that helped you.

Comment: Your answer really helped! Thanks